# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined when using findOneAndRemove()

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

When I execute the function findOneAndRemove() and pass in the required parameters, it shows the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined'. My mongodb have the attribute '_id'

I tried findById(). It is working but if I defined findOneAndRemove({_id: req.params.id}), the error occurs.

```
**router**

router.delete('/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var id = req.params.id;

        if (!ObjectID.isValid(id))
            return res.status(404).send();

        let team = await Team.findOneAndDelete({ _id: id, createdBy: req.user._id });
        console.log('team', team);
        if (!team)
            return res.status(404).send();

            res.status(201).json({
              message: 'Team Deleted',
              result: { team }
            });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }
  });
```

```
**Team Model**

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const teamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true
  },
  country: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  yearFounded: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  ground: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
  },
  capacity: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
  },
  manager: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  website: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  imagePath: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  createdBy: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'User'
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})


teamSchema.index({ name: "text", manager: "text", ground: "text", country: "text" });

teamSchema.virtual('players', {
  ref: 'Player',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'team'
})


const Team = mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema);

module.exports = Team
```

Comment: `console.log(req)`, and see if you get your `user `and see if you can find your key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findOneAndRemove returns the removed document so if you remove a document that you later decide should not be removed, you can insert it back into the db. Ensuring your logic is sound before removing the document would be preferred to checks afterward IMO.

findOneAndDelete has the sort parameter which can be used to influence which document is updated. It also has a TimeLimit parameter which can control within which operation has to complete

try this

```
    router.delete('/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let id = {_id:req.params.id};

        if (!ObjectID.isValid(id))
            return res.status(404).send();

        let team = await Team.findOneAndRemove({ _id: rid, createdBy: req.user._id });
        console.log('team', team);
        if (!team)
            return res.status(404).send();

            res.status(201).json({
              message: 'Team Deleted',
              result: { team }
            });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the explaination. However it is not working, still giving the same error 'TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined' but inside MongoDB, the document have a field _id and when I use findByIdAndRemove it is working.

Comment: Hi After some debugging, i find out the issues. The issue is req.user is undefined and the _id is referring from that params. By adding middleware, which store the req.user information and I am able to get the _id and resolve.

But anyway thanks for the help. (:

Comment: @Sian20R: Welcome

Answer (score 0):

The answer is I forget to add middleware 'authenticate' and hence the createdBy params req.user._id is forever undefined. The solution.

**Routes**

```
router.delete('/delete/:id', authenticate, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var id = req.params.id;

        if (!ObjectID.isValid(id))
            return res.status(404).send();

        let team = await Team.findOneAndRemove({ _id: id, createdBy: req.user._id });
        if (!team)
          return res.status(404).send();

        removeImage(team.imagePath);
        res.status(201).json({
          message: 'Team Deleted',
          result: { team }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }
  });
```

**Middleware**

```
let authenticate = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })

        if (!user) {
            throw new Error()
        }

        req.token = token;
        req.user = user;
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please authenticate.' })
    }
};
```